# Cooktop installation on Granite

Tags: granite, cooktops

I just purchased a new cooktop that it is narrower than the cut out of my granite. Would it be OK to have most of the weight just on the ends and not on the front and back? I have a solution I think for the 1/8 inch gap.

Comment: that depends on what you will be cooking (the wight)

Comment: You want to trust just the two ends to hold the cooktop plus a big pot of boiling water to hold without tipping over on your kid?

Comment: You would be smart to support this from below.

Comment: I would fashion some timber to hold it from below.  You can easily hide it by shifting the cooktop to the front so its supported and put the timber in the back.

Comment: Could even get a piece of matching countertop to put in that space at the back, and support that from underneath...

Comment: I had to replace my cooktop and my first constraint was to choose only those cooktops that matched the hole in the worktop. But if price was your first constraint then consider the cost  and effort for the remedial work. If the gap fill does not provide sufficient strength then it might fail, all those pans full of hot jam...

Comment: @Murphy can you share the dimensions of both the cooktop and cutout?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues.  Granite is not that strong as we discovered by sitting on the kitchen benchtop.  So you are relying on the strength of the lips on cooktop and the strength of edge of the granite to hold the weight.

I would suggest that you fashion some timber to hold it from below. You can easily hide it by shifting the cooktop to the front so it's supported by the granite and putting the timber in the back.  Depending on large the gap is, you could possibly tile the top of the timber to hide it even further and make it more water-proof.

Comment: Timber could work, or even rigging up a bunch of the clamps that are used for undermounting sinks to granite counters.  Use a filler piece if necessary.  OP doesn't say how big the cooktop is, and how big the cutout is.